# Duration of GIF in swift

Tags: swift, gif, animated-gif

I am setting GIF in UIImageView as per following code in Splash Screen.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Splash", withExtension: "gif")

self.imgGifSplash.sd_setImage(with: url!, completed: { (img, error, type, url) in
     // this block is called when Gif is loaded in UIImageView, not when image is completed playing once.

          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.2) { // Change `2.0` to the desired number of seconds.

                    if let _ = UserData.shared.loginData?.token {
                        let VC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVCNav") as! UINavigationController
                        objAppDelegate.window?.rootViewController = VC
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let VC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginNav") as! UINavigationController
                        objAppDelegate.window?.rootViewController = VC
                    }
                }
}
```

I want Gif to be played only once.. So i tried using timer of 3.2 seconds but when i am using different devices then i am getting different results like sometimes it played only once, sometime twice, sometime not even completing once.

How can i achieve a perfect animated splash screen that plays GIF only once ?

Hope to get perfect answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `UIImageView`, set your `animationImages`, `animationDuration` and `animationRepeatCount`

Comment: How will i get `completionHandler` of that image playing?

Comment: You know how long it takes. Just wait the minimum time for it to complete

Comment: Note that `sd_setImage` runs asynchronously. You don't need that for displaying images from your bundle. It's purpose is for loading images from the web

Comment: can you give me code for what you are suggesting me for acheiving my aim?
as i am having .GIF file & i dont know how to set that to animationImages..

Comment: Just get the images from your gif and adtthem separately to your bundle

Comment: @Sneha Have you found a solution?